# Does the kafka JDBC MySQL source connector need to have MySQL Server on localhost?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm pretty new to Kafka and I am trying to get a simple kafka connect system up and running with a MySQL source connector and an Elasticsearch + Elastic search sink connector; for basic data flow purposes.

I'm following the steps from 
https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/
& its part 2
(I have verified that ES works by having a simple producer on the source side.)

Everything is configured and working as expected except the MySQL source connector.
The VM where I am trying all this **does not have MySQL server installed on it**. The DBMS part of the tutorial I am using a client to create/alter and play around with tables.
Hence in the source properties, I tried:

```
"connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://IPaddressofDB:3306/DBname?user=uname&password=pwd"
"table.whitelist": "tablename"
```

To start the connectors, I simply did a `./confluent load connector-name`

As soon as I load the source connector, and check its status, it gives an error that

```
"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed trying to validate that columns used for offsets are NOT NULL\n\t ...
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'admin_portal.tablename' doesn't exist\n\t
```

1. Is this even correct? Am I missing something completely?
2. How to specify connection.url for cases like I am trying: where you are trying to connect to different DB servers? Almost all the examples/git issues etc seem to only specify localhost.
3. I'm not sure where `admin_portal` came from, I have not specified that anywhere at all

****EDITTED for @robin-moffat's suggestions (seems to give the same error as before)

sourceconfig.json:

```
{
        "name": "jdbc_source_mysql_new",
        "config": {
                "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
                "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/dbname?user=uname&password=pwd",
                "table.whitelist": "dbname.tablename",
                "topic.prefix": "mysql-new-",
                "mode":"incrementing",
                "incrementing.column.name": "colname"
                }
}
```

Loaded the connector:

```
>curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @sourceconfig.json http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

Check the status of the connector:

```
>curl -X GET localhost:8083/connectors/jdbc_source_mysql_new/tasks/0/status

  {"state":"FAILED","
     "trace": 
     "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed trying to validate that columns used for offsets are NOT NULL\n\t
     at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask.validateNonNullable(JdbcSourceTask.java:400)\n\t
     at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask.start(JdbcSourceTask.java:156)\n\t
     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:198)\n\t
     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)\n\t
     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)\n\t
     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\t
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\t
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\t
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\t
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n

 Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'admin_portal.tablename' doesn't exist\n\t
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)\n\t
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)\n\t
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)\n\t
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1218)\n\t
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$7.forEach(DatabaseMetaData.java:2950)\n\t
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$7.forEach(DatabaseMetaData.java:2938)\n\t
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.IterateBlock.doForAll(IterateBlock.java:56)\n\t
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getPrimaryKeys(DatabaseMetaData.java:2991)\n\t
 at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.primaryKeyColumns(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:696)\n\t
 at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.describeColumns(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:533)\n\t
 at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.describeColumns(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:513)\n\t
 at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask.validateNonNullable(JdbcSourceTask.java:369)\n\t... 9 more\n",}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with localhost or not: the error indicates you are connected (otherwise it would never have produced a `SQLSyntaxErrorException`). The layout is just not what kafka expected.

Comment: Hi, can you please clarify what is unexpected in this layout?

Comment: The error indicates that kafka is expecting a table that does not exist in your table. Why that is, no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the kafka JDBC MySQL source connector need to have MySQL Server on localhost?

No. It uses JDBC which can connect to a server on a remote instance.

> 1. Is this even correct? Am I missing something completely?

From what you've described, you're on the right lines :)

> 2. How to specify connection.url for cases like I am trying: where you are trying to connect to different DB servers? Almost all the examples/git issues etc seem to only specify localhost.

You can see [an example here](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/connect-jdbc/README.adoc#example-connector-configuration)

You need to configure the JDBC URL correctly, the syntax for which [can be found here for MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html).

> 3. I'm not sure where admin_portal came from, I have not specified that anywhere at all

This will be down to the permissions of the user with which you're connecting to the database. You need to make sure that it has access to the table from which you want to read data. You can also qualify your table name, e.g.

```
"table.whitelist": "schema.tablename"
```

Comment: Thanks @robin. Let me check this out right away. So, if I understand it correctly, i just need to use the REST APIs of kafka-connect for remote servers which wouldn't be needed in case of localhost.

Comment: Hi @Robin, thanks for the suggestion. However I am still running into the same error. I have edited the question to show what I tried. I also tried the bulk mode first but ran into the same error

Answer (score 2):

It worked after I downgraded the My SQL connector version from 8.x to 5.1.47 and placed it in the right $CLASSPATH

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar
```